# Good trust account in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, trusts

We need to open a trust account for our children for some money they inherited in trust.  We were warned that quite a few of the banks are quite reluctant to do this. So the main questions are:

1. Once its in trust in the account can we move it again?
2. Do the trust accounts pay any interest?
3. Can we invest the money on their behalf?  How does that work with a "trust" account?

Comment: Where is it now? The question implies it's already in a trust.

Comment: i guess it is. it's a cheque from the solicitor naming the trustees

Comment: The trust will contain the details of how it's to be disbursed, and hopefully how it should be invested if it has time to run. As it stands, the question can't be answered with the details as given.

Comment: There is no detail on how it should be invested, merely that they can get it when they're 18.

Comment: Are you designated as trustee?

Comment: yup and my Wife too.

Comment: Sorry we don't have more members answering from the UK. In the States, a trust is fairly simple after it's set up. Any broker here will create the account, title it in accordance with the trust documents, and let you (and the Mrs) act as trustees. You invest the money and disburse it as the trust dictates. I'll clean up the comments if a UK member provides a detailed answer.

Comment: Does it have to be a trust? For example, might a [Junior ISA](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/investing/article-1587994/Junior-Isa-Child-Trust-Fund-How-save-invest-children.html) do the job? If the inheritance is more than the annual ISA limit (now £15,000 p.a.), then a proper trust may need to be set up; for that you may need to speak to a solicitor who specialises in trusts.

Comment: Well the money is already in "trust"  (whatever that means!) However i've found out that hargreaves lansdown do a "bare trust" account and this looks very suitable.  I've also found out that we just need a trust account to pay it into initially but then as trustees we can pay it out and into an investment account. so its all just legal gumf basically.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm answering your second and third point. For first point it depends on case by case basis from which organization you are opening your trust.*

Trust Account are of different type: To earn interest you account should be of below type.
**Interest in possession trusts and Income Tax**

Trustees are responsible for declaring and paying Income Tax on income received by the trust. They do this on a Trust and Estate Tax Return each year.

There are different rates depending on the type of income - as shown below.
*Type of income     Income Tax rate 2014 to 2015 tax year*

**Rent, trading and savings     20% (basic rate)**
**UK dividends (such as income from stocks and shares)  10% (dividend ordinary rate)**